# How can I fill a listview in vertical form?

Tags: c#, listview

I have one listview whith several columns.
I want to fill this listview in a vertical form
column to column.

Comment: WinForms        
by c#    
please answer me

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this is not (easily) possible.

A `ListView` has a list of `ListViewItem`s, where each one has a List of `ListViewSubItem`s (and to make it a little more complex at the first spot, the first `ListViewSubItem` is the same as the `ListViewItem` itself).

So if you like to fill up a `ListView` column by column you first have to add the `ListViewItem`s to the `ListView` for all the values you want in the first column.

Afterwards you iterate through the `ListView.Items` and call on every `ListViewItem.Subitems.Add` to fill up the next column. This must be done for each column you like to fill.

If you like to fill in the column values in another order then from left to right, you should take a look into the [`DisplayIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.columnheader.displayindex.aspx) of the `ColumnHeader` within the `ListView.Columns`.

Some example code:

```
// Some values
var someValues = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);

// Fill up the first column
foreach (var item in someValues)
{
    listView.Items.Add("0." + item);
}

// Run for each column in the listView (the first is already filled up)
foreach (ColumnHeader column in listView.Columns.Cast<ColumnHeader>().Skip(1))
{
    // Get the value and the index for which row the value should be
    foreach (var item in someValues.Select((Value, Index) => new { Value, Index }))
    {
        // Add the value to the given row, thous leading to be added as new column
        listView.Items[item.Index].SubItems.Add(column.Index + "." + item.Value);
    }
}
```